# Assigning python deque to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, deque

The problem is to rotate a list by moving the numbers from the right, k times. e.g. [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] with k=3 will rotate the numbers from the right one at a time and move them to the top of the list so the output would be [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]. Rather than using the pop and insert operation in the list, I decided to use the dequue data type in python that supports adding to the left of the list in O(1). However, I am not quite sure how the conversion happens from dequeue to list. The second function works whereas the first doesn't. If you can explain why, it would be much appreciated.

```
from collections import deque

def rotateNums(nums, k):
  dq = deque(nums)
  for _ in range(0,k):
    num = dq.pop()
    dq.appendleft(num)
  nums = list(dq)

def rotateNums(nums, k):
  dq = deque(nums)
  for _ in range(0,k):
    num = dq.pop()
    dq.appendleft(num)
  nums[:] = list(dq)

nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
k = 3
print(f'nums before rotation: {nums}')
rotateNums(nums, k)
print(f'nums after rotation: {nums}')
```

Output from the first function is: nums after rotation: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Output from the second function is: [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: Assigning a newly-created list to `nums` breaks the connection you had to the list that was passed into the function.  Nothing you do with the new `nums` is visible outside of the function.  (Note that rotating a list can be done much easier than this: `nums[-k:] + nums[:-k]`.)

Comment: `deque` has a `.rotate()` built-in, so you can just write `yourdeque.rotate(3)`

Comment: @jasonharper slicing produces new objects

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not in the conversation from deque to list, which you do correctly with `nums[:] = list(dq)` in both cases. It's with the line `nums = list(dq)` in the first function. This reassigns the name `num` to a different list object locally in the function. The subsequent replacement operation operates on a local object, not the list you passed in.

On a side note, you don't need to explicitly convert `dq` back to a list to assign it. It's already iterable, and a sequence, so you can do `nums[:] = dq` just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to scoping. In the first function, you are assigning the value of `deque` to `nums` with this code, `nums = list(dq)`. This tells python that this `nums` is a local variable to the function `rotateNums`. So it has no effect in the outside `nums`. Instead, if you did this:

```
def rotateNums(nums, k):
  dq = deque(nums)
  for _ in range(0,k):
    num = dq.pop()
    dq.appendleft(num)
  nums = list(dq)
  nums[:] = list(dq)
  return nums
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
k = 3
print(f'nums before rotation: {nums}')
nums = rotateNums(nums, k)
print(f'nums after rotation: {nums}')
```

The output will be:

```
nums before rotation: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
nums after rotation: [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Whereas in the second one, by calling `nums[:] =` you are **accessing** and modifying the elements of `nums`, which is permitted and does not create a local variable `nums`.

Comment: If you're going to return the list, `nums[:] = list(dq)` is pointless. Also, `nums` is a local variable, not a local function. That being said, the gist of this answer is ok.

Comment: Yes, there is no point I agree. It is an attempt to show how it works, and the function thing is a pure typo. Let me edit that.